# Is there a better way to expand <div>s outside a wrapper?

Tags: html, css

I have a site template where everything is inside a wrapper `<div>`

HTML

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='contact'>
       an image 
    </div>
    <div id='header'>
       an image 
    </div>
    <div id='menu'>
        | menu 1 | menu 2 |
    </div>
    <div id='content'>
        jhskjhjkdhkjashklsajhkdjas
    </div>
    <div id='footer-wrapper'>
       <div id='footer'>
           footer content
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='gmap'>
       google map
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {border:1px solid; max-width:500px; width:100%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
#menu, #contact, #gmap   {background-color: #CCCCCC; width:100%;}
#footer {background-color:#FFFFFF; width:100%;}
#footer-wrapper {padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; background-color: #000000;}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vt2ma4p4/2/)

in the designs i have been tasked to work on the design shows that the grey and black expand outside `wrapper` at the width of the entire page yet the text/content within remains aligned as it currently is (as if still inside `#wrapper`)

currently i have been taught to move all the areas i want to expanded outside `wrapper` and into their own wrapper `div` while their actual `div` is centered with the same method as wrapper.

to me however that seems clunky as if someone wants to change the width of `#wrapper` while keeping the rest of the content inline with it they have to change it in multiple places. not to mention the template seems kind redudent if i have to break it up so bad just so i can get color to expand across the entire page

i am wondering if there is a better way to expand `#menu`, `#contact`, `#footer-wrapper` across the entire page while keeping them inside `#wrapper`

NOTE: `#wrapper`'s width remains as it is. it's just the `<div>`'s mentioned who's background color should be expanding outside #wrapper, similar to [This Site](http://coachoncollins.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you could set the `max-width` and centering stuff on each `div` inside the `wrapper`, see the minimal demo follows.

```css
#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#wrapper > div {
    border:1px solid black;
    max-width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='header'>1</div>
    <div id='content'>2</div>
    <div id='footer'>3</div>
</div>
```

Well, if you really need the inner `div` to expand outside the `wrapper`, it is possible too.

```css
#wrapper {
    border:1px solid black;
    max-width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#content {
    border:1px solid blue;
    min-width:90vw;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='header'>1</div>
    <div id='content'>2</div>
    <div id='footer'>3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont need the #wrapper div. just create a reusable `.content` class. then every different section will have this inner content div to center your conetnt and set it to the correct width

http://jsfiddle.net/vt2ma4p4/4/

```
<div class="header"> <!-- color goes on this div -->
   <div class="content">my content</div> <!-- width and centering on this one -->
</div>
```

```
.header {
   background-color: #eee;
}
.content {
   max-width: 500px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust the `#wrapper`'s `max-width` to your liking
i.e. 1000px

Or better yet, do not limit the `max-width` at all.  Depends on your needs.

```
#wrapper {
    border:1px solid;
    max-width:1000px; /* adjust width here or remove this line */
    width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

[**See updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vt2ma4p4/3/)

Comment: Oh sorry, i thought it was clear. `#wrapper` stays as it is, so the greay should be going outside `#wrapper` while the text stays aligned as if the div is still in `#wrapper`